# Docker delete file on stop of container

Tags: django, docker, celery

i have a django app that also uses cerlery and celery also creates a .pid file but if i restart my app with docker-compose up celery fails to start because the old .pid file within the container does not get deleted,
what can i do to solve this isse?
Is there maybe a way on linux-side (debian 9) to remove the file at restart or shutdown of the container?

snippet of my docker config:

```
celery:
    image: echo_echo
    command: bash -c "celery worker -A echo -l INFO --pidfile="/tmp/celery/celery.pid" "
    volumes:
      - echo:/echo
...
```

Thanks and br

Comment: Can you add your docker-compose configuration? Are you using volumes? (We are running celery inside a docker container without problems.)

Comment: snipped has been addedto the question.

Comment: We do not use the `--pidfile` option, and we don't have problems restarting the container. Could you try without it?

Comment: Same result ... otherwise i wouldn't use that location at all.

Comment: How do you shut down? are you sure that you are using `docker-compose down`?

Comment: Ctrl+C currently.
the funny fact is that even if do  --pidfile="/tmp/celerybeat.pid
The file does not get deletet after Start/Stop/Start?? of the env.

Comment: It is in the container which is only deleted if it is removed via `docker rm <container-id>` or `docker-compose down`. I'm wondering why it works for us, though, without doing removing it... If you could add some parts of you Dockerfile/docker-entrypoint.sh - maybe it is some special setup that you do there?

Comment: @Venom can you try (after the Ctrl+C) to explicitly run `docker-compose down`? it should remove the containers. Then run `docker-compose up` again and see if you still see that pid file

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue fixed, i simply added the (pid) file like so:

```
--pidfile= --schedule=/var/run/celerybeat-schedule
and also for the worker(s):
--pidfile= --schedule=/var/run/celery-schedule
```